# How do I identify rows containing a minimum number of distinct words from a candidate list?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a list of words as well as a dataset.  I would like to identify rows within the dataset that have at least two of the words in the list.

I am able to identify rows containing at least two of the list words, but my code problematically also identifies rows where a single list word is repeated.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    
data={'Name':['Redred','redblue','redgreen','blue']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Good colours'] = (df['Name'].str.contains("(red.*|blue.*|green.*){2,}",case=False, regex=True))

print(df)
```

In the resulting dataset, the row 'redred' returns true when it should not.

In an effort to exclude repeated words I've tried `(red.*){1,}(blue.*){1,}(green.*){1}` but this means that 'redblue' and 'redgreen' is no longer recognized (and it is essential for the code to recognize these rows.)

How do I write the regex so it identifies two instances of the list words while excluding repeated instances of the list word?

Comment: Do you want to test for full row, or just cells (i.e., a single column)?

Comment: A single column :-)

Comment: You may want to update your question then. In fact, I'm not sure why you need Pandas for that. The problem can be stated with a list of words and a regular expression (and the solution in Pandas will be identical).

Comment: Thank you for asking these questions.  To clarify, the above represents a toy dataset, but in real life I have a dataset with many columns.  I only want the code to run on one column though.

Comment: What about a string like "redredgreen", or "greenredred", or "redgreenred"?

Comment: In MY opinion, this is beyond what one should do with a regular expression.  I would think you will need to do `s.count('red')`, `s.count('green')`, `s.count('blue')`, then reject if any value is > 1.  This may require `apply()`.

Comment: @9769953 Good question. It is not supposed to fail for any rows that have two instances of the list words, regardless of repetition.  It is only supposed to fail when there is only one instance of the list word.

Comment: To be clear: the problem with `redred` is **not** that "red" is repeated, but that it only contains *one distinct colour value*, correct?

Comment: Yes!  @KarlKnechtel thank you for articulating the issue more clearly.

Comment: Can there be *other* words, or more general, letters in your input? Say, "123red", or "littleredhousewithabluedoor", is that possible?

Comment: Yes, my real dataset has the list words interspersed with general words (ie. '123red')

Comment: I think your chosen solution doesn't work for such strings. "123redred" returns `True`.

Comment: @9769953 you are right.

Comment: I edited the question title to reflect this new understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes regex isn't the tool for the job.

I would simply use separate calls to determine which rows contain red, green and blue, and then see which ones are in at least two of those groups.

```py
def name_has_color(df, color):
    return df['Name'].str.contains(color, case=False).astype(int)

color_counts = sum(
    name_has_color(df, color)
    for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']
)

df['good_colors'] = (color_counts >= 2)
```

This approach is naturally extensible and will not get more complex if you need to check for a larger number of contained values or if there are more  looked-for values.

Comment: I think this solution is quicker and may be more adaptable to large lists. Will test on real dataset.

Comment: When I add a new column in the dataset (ie `data={'Name':['123Redred','redblue','redredgreen','blue'],'OtherCol':['1','2','3','4']}` I get the error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.  As the error has to do with the new column, I thought the code might need to specify the row (ie `df['good_colors'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: color_counts(x) >= 2)`) but this did not work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd. I originally wrote the code to filter the rows (`df = df[color_counts >= 2]`). `color_counts >= 2` is already the data that should be used to populate `df['good_colors']` for the problem *as you described it*; using it as a mask causes the error, because the data no longer lines up. The code is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
(df['Name'].str.contains(r"^(?!(red|blue|green)\1+$)(?:.*(?:red|blue|green)){2}",case=False, regex=True))
```

If your strings must only consist of words from the list remove `.*`, and replace `{2}` with `{2,}$`:

```py
(df['Name'].str.contains(r"^(?!(red|blue|green)\1+$)(?:red|blue|green){2,}$",case=False, regex=True))
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(red|blue|green)\1+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is

  - `(red|blue|green)` - Group 1: any of the substrings defined in the group
  - `\1+` - one or more repetitions of Group 1 value and then
  - `$` - end of string
- `(?:.*(?:red|blue|green)){2}` - two occurrences of zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then an single occurrence of the substrings defined in the group.
- `(?:red|blue|green){2,}$` -  two or more occurrences of  the word from group and then end of string.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/SR1QDF/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/CY78sk/1).

Comment: Just to clarify: Blue is supposed to fail.  'redredgreen' isn't suppose to fail.  Thank you for working on this Wiktor.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear.  In cases where there are two instances of a list word, I want the row to be true.  I want the row to be false when there is only one (repeated) instance of a list word.

Comment: @oymonk Ok, I updated the answer. You might want to use `trieregex` library if you have long lists of `blue`, `red`, etc. keywords.

Comment: I do have long lists so thanks for the redirect to trieregex.

Comment: Looks like "123redred" returns `True`, which I understand it's not supposed to do.

Comment: @9769953 What makes you think so?

Comment: @oymonk Are you sure you need a regex solution?

Comment: Which part? For the first part, I checked with the OP (comment under the question); for the second part, I simply tested your solution.

Comment: @9769953 My [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/CY78sk/1) does not return True for "123redred".

Comment: Which was added after my initial comment, so I don't understand your question: my comment is (was) about the then current solution, which didn't work.